# Prove that every ideal $I$ of $\Bbb C[x, y]$ that contains $K$ can be generated by two elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Let $\varphi: \Bbb C [x, y] \to \Bbb C [t]$ be the homomorphism that sends $x \mapsto t + 1$ and $y \mapsto t^3-1$. Determine the kernel $K$ of $\varphi$, and prove that every ideal $I$ of $\Bbb C[x, y]$ that contains $K$ can be generated by two elements.

I have that $\ker \varphi$ is generated by the polynomial $P(x,y)=y-(x-1)^3 +1$. For the second part since $\varphi$ is surjective we have that $\Bbb C[x,y] / \ker \varphi \cong \Bbb C[t]$. So as $\Bbb C[t]$ is a PID we have that $\Bbb C[x,y] / \ker \varphi$ is a PID which implies that any ideal in $\Bbb C[x,y] / \ker \varphi$ is principal. So if $\ker\varphi \subset I$  for some ideal $I$ in $\Bbb C[x,y] / \ker \varphi$ we have that $I/\ker\varphi = (f)$ for some $f \in \Bbb C[x,y]$.

I'm trying to prove now that $(f,P)= I$, but I don't now how to go about this. Since $\ker \varphi \subset I$ I suppose I have that $(f,P) \subset I$ just because $P$ generates $\ker \varphi$.

The other direction is hard. If I take $g \in I$, then I can express $g(x,y)=P(x,y)q(x,y) + r(x)$ and now since $$(f,P) = \{a_1 f + a_2P \mid a_1,a_2 \in \Bbb C[x,y]\}$$ I would be done if I can show that $r(x)  \in (f) = I /\ker\varphi$? How can I show this?

Edit: By the correspondence theorem I have that since by assumption $\ker \varphi \subset I$, then $\varphi (I)$ is an ideal of $\Bbb C[t]$. Now since $\Bbb C[t]$ is a PID we have that $\varphi(I)=(g)$ for some $g \in \Bbb C[t]$. If I pull this back to $\Bbb C[x,y]$ I have that $\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(I)) = I$ so $\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(I)) = (g)$?

Comment: Write $I/(P)=(\bar f)$ for some $f\in I$. So $(f,P)\subseteq I$ and for every element $a\in I$ we have $\bar a\in(\bar f)$. Then there is $g\in k[x,y]$ such that $a-fg\in (P)$. This implies that $a\in(f,P)$. (Here the bar stands for the residue classes in the quotient ring $k[x,y]/(P)$.)

Comment: How do you get the implication that if $\bar a\in(\bar f)$, then $\exists g \in k[x,y]$ such that $a-fg \in (P)?$

Comment: From $\bar a=\bar f\bar g$ by lifting the bars.

Comment: I see. That would although imply that $\bar a - \bar f \bar g = 0$ so how come is the element $a-fg$ in $(P) = \{qP \mid q \in \Bbb C[x,y] \}$?